# Create a file in bin-debug with File.applicationDirectory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file-io, actionscript, flash-builder

When debugging in Flash Builder, the output folder is usually `bin-debug`.

I am creating a file if it doesn't exist. The file is located at the installation directory:

```
configFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
```

When debugging, this will save the file to `bin-debug`.  The problem is that `bin-debug` is marked as **read only**.  Thus I am getting a `SecurityError: fileWriteResource`.

I want to use `File.applicationDirectory` because it has multi-platform support and it will create the file in the installation directory.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: For future reference, you should use `applicationStorageDirectory` instead of `applicationDirectory` for saving files. Depending on security settings and the actual OS (unless something has changed, I was never able to write there on iOS), you may not be able to write to applicationDirectory at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything the right way. If you think that problem lies in the permissions, try changing the file path like this:

```
configFile = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
```

If this works use it while debugging and change it back when releasing the project.

Comment: In my opinion, release/environment specifics shouldn't require code changes.  These kinds of things should be in a config file of sorts.  But thanks for the answer!